# Is it possible to set arbitrary ip address to tcpClient?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I got a *diagnostic program* to work with network of hardware equipment. Interconnection is based on TCP protocol. *Diagnostic program* is server and uses **TcpListener** to listen for connections, hardware acts as client which connects to server and transmit data. Ip addresses of *diagnostic program* and hardware equipment are predefined and must be unchanged, diagnostic program await only predefined hardware ip addresses.
Ip address of diagnostic program is 192.168.1.11, hardware equipment's - 192.168.1.200, 192.168.1.201, etc.

```
+--------------+     +---------------+  
| [server]     |<--->| [hw client1]  |  
|              |     | 192.168.1.200 |  
| diagnostic   |     +---------------+  
| program      |     +---------------+  
| 192.168.1.11 |<--->| [hw client2]  |  
+--------------+     | 192.168.1.201 |  
                     +---------------+
```

Hardware currently implements part of internal protocol and *diagnostic program* works fine. I want to improve *diagnostic program* and implement next part of internal protocol without hardware equipment (its software not ready). To do this I want to implement software emulator to work as hardware. My plan is to create **tcpClient**, which implements internal protocol used in interaction between *diagnostic program* and hardware equipment.
The problem is that I cannot set arbitrary ip address to **tcpClient**. I can only work through **localhost**.
Is it possible to create program which will implement **tcpClient** with desired ip address (for example 192.168.1.200)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another approach.
I wanted solution which will not impact my diagnostic program in any way.
I used virtual machine (by means of *virtualbox*). Main problem was to properly set up ip addresses of host and vitrual machine. Host machine is 192.168.1.11, inside virtual machine - 192.168.1.200.
As a result, diagnostic program is unchanged, client runs at virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to switch your NIC from using a DHCP address.

[image: IPV4 Properites]

Then open the advanced settings and add the second IP address.

[image: Advanced TCP/IP Settings]

Comment: Please, don't change global system settings to solve a local problem.  (Even the global effects of putting a NIC in promiscuous mode are bad enough... changing the system IP address list for the sake of one network tester application is far far worse).  Besides that, you failed to provide a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets make a more detailed version of your diagram.

[image]

Instead of faking a IP address TcpClient talks to, fake TcpClient instead.

so basically your program would turn in to.

[image]

This is very similar in principal as using a "[Mock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163904.aspx)" when unit testing. All you need to do is make a interface that the main logic talks to that wraps up the TCP communication, when talking to real hardware it goes to a real client class object, when talking to your emulator it talks to your emulator class which implements the same interface.